# Cannot write a file on Windows 7 when the program is started using hkcu...run or task scheduler

Tags: windows, uac, file-handling

I was creating a program that runs on startup. I simply writes a file.

I already have set permission of the containing folder to: Full Control=Allow for all users and group listed.

I've also tried using task scheduler, run with elevated priviliges.

But none is working...

Although it works properly (the file is written) when the program is run normaly (by clicking the file in the explorer).

Comment: Where is a file? Is it on a network drive or `subst`ed drive? Is its name hardcoded in the program, and if so, don't you omit the directory so it's written to whatever directory happens to be current? (If so, then fix it, use full pathname instead).

Comment: Thank you, it is now working. But why does it need to have an absolute path?

Comment: Because you don't know which directory is current when your program is run. (You *seem* to know it for "clicking in the explorer", but did you read it in documentation, or just noticed that it's so? Anyway, even **if** this property of explorer is documented and real, there is no such promise for other ways to run a program).